# Django Development: Chrome warns "Change Password"

Tags: python, django, google-chrome

im new at django and for learning i create a fantasy project. By testing my website i was been warned from my Chrome browser that i should change my password. The exact message is

> Due to a data breach on a website or in an app your password was disclosed. Chrome recommends changing your password to 127.0.0.1:8000.

is there anything in my code that makes this data breach?

Thanks for helping!

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):

username = forms.CharField(
    label='Benutzername',
    max_length=150,
    required=True,
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Username',
        }
    )
)

email = forms.EmailField(
    label='E-Mail Adresse',
    max_length=254,
    required=True,
    widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'email@exapmle.com',
        }
    )
)

password = forms.CharField(
    label='Passwort',
    max_length=254,
    required=True,
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Password',
        }
    )
)

repeatPassword = forms.CharField(
    label='Passwort wiederholen',
    max_length=254, required=True,
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Password',
        }
    )
)

name = forms.CharField(
    label='Nachname',
    max_length=150,
    required=False,
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Last Name',
        }
    )
)

firstName = forms.CharField(
    label='Vorname',
    max_length=150,
    required=False,
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'First name',
        }
    )
)

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(RegisterForm, self).clean()
    username = cleaned_data.get('username')
    email = cleaned_data.get('email')
    password = cleaned_data.get('password')
    repeatPassword = cleaned_data.get('repeatPassword')
    name = cleaned_data.get('name')
    firstName = cleaned_data.get('firstName')

    if not username:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Enter Username')

    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Username is taken by another one")

    if not email:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Enter E-Mail')

    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("E-Mail is taken by another one")

    if not password:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Enter password')

    if not repeatPassword:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Repeat password')

    if password != repeatPassword:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords are not equal')
```

views.py

```
def register_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username'], email=request.POST['email'],
                                        password=request.POST['password'], first_name=request.POST['firstName'],
                                        last_name=request.POST['name'])

        user.save()

        # Get Created User from DB
        user = authenticate(request, username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        if user:
            # LogIn (create Session etc...)
            login(request, user)

            # open user.html
            return render(request, 'web/user.html')
    return render(request, 'web/register.html', {'form': form})
else:
    form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'web/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Its not saying your app or account is compromised, it just means you are using a super weak password that has been pwnd (like password123). If you're just creating an account for local testing then don't worry about it, but you probably shouldn't use that password in real life. See here: https://security.googleblog.com/2019/12/better-password-protections-in-chrome.html

Comment: okay thanks for your help. This Message is really confusing :D

Comment: freaked me out the first time, thats for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this message is just an information, that a weak password is used.
Thanks to Tenacious B for clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, Chrome does show such warning when you use a weak password.No need to worry about it.